# What do they mean saying SYSTEM MEMORY

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I am working on an embedded application. 
Trying to configure the DMA controller I came across to the statement:

> You must provide an area
>    of system memory to contain the channel control data structure

What do they mean saying **system memory**? Data SRAM? Code SRAM? Somewhere else?

You can find that statement at the beginning of section **8.4.3** here: 
http://www.silabs.com/support%20documents/technicaldocs/efm32wg-rm.pdf

Comment: Explain the downvote.

Comment: Just how would it make sense to DMA data to/from code memory? Of course they mean plain data RAM.

Comment: It is physically possible actually to read and write into the code memory.

Comment: According to the manual you linked, no. I don't see how it would make sense to do so either. Do you even have code SRAM to begin with? Sounds like a PC in disguise, rather than a microcontroller. Running code from RAM is very bad practice in any embedded system.

Comment: Yes I have code SRAM. And i have seen many cases where the ram is used for code memory. Especially during firmware update.

Comment: Non-paged..............

Comment: @Lundin: Not really. Faster Cortex-M MCU like STM32F7 have close-coupled code-RAM (IRAM) e.g. for interrupt handlers and other code which need fast execution. This simply because Flash is too slow and either they don't have instruction cache or to prevent such code from trashing other code from the cache and avoid the latency to prefetch the first instructions from Flash. Typically the RAM is loaded at startup (much like the `.data` section) and the area is write-protected, e.g. using the MPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DMA measn Direct Memory Access. The idea is that a module like the ADC is not raising an iterrupt to ask the CPU to read its new data. Instead the module is directly writting on the memory of the uController. This saves performes time for the CPU. For configuration you must must create a heap structure and passing the pointer to the module. This allows the module directly change the memory content. So its your heap which is part of your SRAM.

Comment: the global variables are not residing into the heap, but they are guaranteed to be allocated for the entire life cycle of the program. So is it OK to put that structure into the ram allocated for the global variables?

Comment: The hardware wouldn't care, to be honest, if it was in .bss, .heap, or .data.   What's important is its in the right physical address range.

Comment: dma does not necessarily save any time for the cpu, it is design dependent, sometimes it only saves programmers time.  Depends on the bus conflicts created by the dma.  some dma designs the cpu is held off from any accesses until the dma transfer completes,  some designs the dma has the highest priority so the cpu suffers as a slave having to take what cycles it can get on the shared bus.  and some designs the dma is the slave so the cpu has some small hit but not as big as if it were doing everything.

Comment: sometimes dma is able to do more efficient transfers than the instruction set and the cpu is held off and waits.  so you have to for each time you see/use dma understand what the system impact is, it isnt automatically better than doing it in code.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of it as I read it, is System Memory is allocated from the on chip  RAM Memory ( Fig 3.1) not external memory mapped or flash program memory.
You see in the Table 3.2 it show the chips have Flash and internal RAM. I'd say the System Memory is the RAM, not the Flash memory. 
Section 3.2 says the features of the chip is that is has 32KB of RAM on chip.
Check figure 5.2 for System Address Space. You'll need to allocate your
DMA_CTRLBASE and DMA_ALTCTRLBASE register within that region, 0x20000000 - 0x20007fff  appropriately to fit the control structure.  Hope that helps.